# SUBQUERY with three tables and attribute value equals the other attribute value

Tags: sql, core-data, subquery, nspredicate

Is it possible to write a SUBQUERY where I want the All values in ‘A’ Where 'idc' CONTAINS 'ida' [image]

Comment: What type are `ida`, `idb` and `idc`?  And what do you mean by "CONTAINS"?

Comment: Both are NSString. CONTAINS means value of 'ida' is a substring of value 'idc'

Comment: Thanks.  And B->C is one to many, so do you want to select where ANY Cs match, or ALL of them?

Comment: All items in A where Idc contains ida

Comment: Did you try "ANY br.cr.idc CONTAINS ida"?

Comment: Now I have tried that. App got crashed with error 'unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (ANY br.cr.idc CONTAINS ida) (LHS and RHS both keypaths)'

Comment: Apparently "attributeA == attributeB" works and "attributeA CONTAINS attributeB" doesn't.

Comment: Jeff, As you see from your error, the real sticking point is using CONTAINS with two key paths.  This doesn't work when fetching from a SQLite store, since CoreData uses its own 'contains' function which won't accept two key paths.  But I think it will work if you fetch ALL the As (no predicate), and then filter the resulting array using the predicate @Willeke suggests.

Comment: Is there any single subquery to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like the following:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM [A] a 
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        idc 
    FROM
        [C]
) c_sub
ON a.ida = c_sub.idc
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Do you know how to use this as NSPredicate